# Apache Commons CLI argument value

Tags: apache-commons-cli

I am trying to write a program which when executed
java -jar -cf file.txt
will retrieve the value of the cf argument. The code I have so far is:

```
Options options = new Options();

final Option configFileOption = Option.builder("cf")
                        .longOpt("configfile")
                        .desc("Config file for Genome Store").argName("cf")
                        .build();

options.addOption(configFileOption);

CommandLineParser cmdLineParser = new DefaultParser();
CommandLine commandLineGlobal= cmdLineParser.parse(options, commandLineArguments);

if(commandLineGlobal.hasOption("cf")) {
        System.out.println(commandLineGlobal.getOptionValue("cf"));
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that the value which is being printed is null. Could anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A useful method to find out why it does not work is to print out the help-information of commons-cli

```
    // automatically generate the help statement
    HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
    formatter.printHelp( "sample", options );
```

this prints

```
usage: sample
 -cf,--configfile   Config file for Genome Store
```

Which indicates that with longOpt() you are specifying an alias for the option, not the arg-value. The correct code to do what you want is:

```
    final Option configFileOption = Option.builder("cf")
                            .argName("configfile")
                            .hasArg()
                            .desc("Config file for Genome Store")
                            .build();
```

which correctly prints

```
usage: sample
 -cf <configfile>   Config file for Genome Store
```

and reports the passed argument to -cf correctly as well.

See the [javadoc of the Option class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html) for more details.